# If $n^2=ab$ and $\gcd(a,b)=1$, show that $a,b$ are not necessarily squares.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I'm reading Stillwell's: *Elements of Number Theory*

> If $a$ and $b$ are relatively prime integers whose product is a square, show by means of an example that $a$ and $b$ are *not* necessarily squares. If they are not squares, what are they?

I did the following:

$$n^2=ab$$

I guess that $a=1^2,b=n^2$ or vice-versa. Because $\gcd(n^2,1)=1$. And hence $n=1^2n^2$, is that it? $1$ is a square, but it's not a square (not in the same sense of $2^2$, for example. $1^n$ is idempotent, $2^n$ is not.)

Comment: What on earth does "1 is a square but it's not a square" mean?

Comment: In your example $a=1^2$ and $b=n^2$ *are* squares, so that is not of relevance here. (Also you mean $n^2=ab$ instead of $n=a^2b^2$). Just because $1$ is *also* a cube etc., does not mean it's not a square ($64=8^2$ is also a cube).

Comment: @HenningMakholm I  explained a little further in the text.

Comment: $-4$  and $-9$, say.

Comment: @JesusChrist: That explanation makes no sense to me. (It might make sense to a being who understands how three can be one, separate and yet one, though).

Comment: May be $a,b$ are primes or both equals $1$.

Comment: Let's not drag Banach Tarski into this...

Answer (score 2):

$1$ is definitely a square.  It is not "not a square".

Hint: $-1$ is not a square.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Find all pairs of $a,b\in\mathbb Z$ such that $n=ab$ for the case $n=1$.

Comment: Oh. $-1\cdot -1$ and $1 \cdot 1$. I guess I understand it.

Comment: And the author actually gave a similar hint in the beginning of the questions and I completely missed it. I'm so stupid.